# Torch tensor with i-th element as product of all previous

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, tensor

I have a torch tensor like this one:

```
A = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

there's in torch a simple way to generate a tensor like this?

```
[1, 1*2, 1*2*3, 1*2*3*4, 1*2*3*4*5, 1*2*3*4*5*6]
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.cumprod`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cumprod.html):

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
torch.cumprod(t, dim=0)
```

which outputs:

```
tensor([1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720])
```

Comment: could you post the output of the function cumprod() pls?